# How can I change the displayed FrameTicks?

Tags: plotting, ticks

How can I change my FrameTicks in this way?

[image]

My code is this:

```
f[x_, ITERATIONS_] := Sum[j*Exp[x*j], {j, 1, ITERATIONS}]/
  Sum[Exp[x*j], {j, 1, ITERATIONS}];
Plot[
 {Legended[Style[f[x, 10], Black, Thin], 
   Placed[Style["\[LeftAngleBracket]j\[RightAngleBracket]", 
     FontSize -> 24], Top]], Style[10, Dashed, Gray]},
 {x, 0, 50},
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific",
 FrameStyle -> Directive[ FontSize -> 18, Black],
 ImageSize -> Large,
 AspectRatio -> 1/2,
 FrameLabel -> {Style["x (= \[CurlyEpsilon] / k_BT)", Black, 
    FontSize -> 18], 
   Style["\[LeftAngleBracket]j\[RightAngleBracket]", Black, 
    FontSize -> 18]},
 PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 3}, {5, 10.5}},
 FrameTicks -> {{ {(10 + 1)/2, 10}, None},  {{0}, None}}
 ]
```

And the result is

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
FrameTicks -> {{{{(10 + 1)/2, HoldForm[(N + 1)/2]}, {10, N}}, None}, {{0}, None}}
```

to get

[image]

or

```
FrameTicks -> {{{{(10 + 1)/2, Style[(N + 1)/2, SingleLetterItalics -> False]}, 
  {10, Style[N, SingleLetterItalics -> False]}}, None}, {{0}, None}}
```

to get

[image]

You can find various forms to specify tick marks in [`Ticks >> Details`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html):

[image]

Comment: Where can I found more information about FrameTicks arguments?

Comment: @tajiri_numero_1, updated with a link to the documentation page.